# try to set GPIO.output(x, LOW) but connected LED still lights

Tags: gpio, output

I try to make a LED light up with the code
[image]

```
        import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
        import time 

        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
        GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
        while (var==1):
          GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)

          GPIO.cleanup()
```

as illustrated in the figure, the pin 18 serves to light up a LED or switch it Down but when I try with sudo python3 this script I see that the LED is lighten just a bit. Only if I connect my transistor base to the ground, I see that the LED is off completely I conclude that pin 18 is between HIGH and LOW, ont completely LOW... why?

Comment: the LED is incorrectly oriented ... it will not light even if the transistor is bridged

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear exactly what you have done (list full code & connections).
What is R_US

The fundamental problem is your circuit.

Using an emitter follower is POOR practice; it will attempt to put 2.7V across the LED when ON, overloading the GPIO with unpredictable results. You have shown the LED connected in reverse.

Try a more conventional circuit; the LED & resistor in series would form the load. See https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits

NOTE with normal LED you can drive (up to 16mA) directly from the GPIO.

[image]